# How do I save the indices of the top 4 maximum numbers in a matrix in scilab

Tags: matlab, scilab

I need to save the indices of 4 maximum numbers
for example, I need to get the indices of rows 10,9,7,5

```
5.0259327
4.7127487
4.8435524
4.8538644
5.1048996
6.2441973
5.9413803
6.2912638
5.1117512
5.8309519
5.7419509
6.9663477
5.9958319
6.9519781
6.5802736
6.7327558
7.6765878
```

I have used

```
[mA,nA]=max(distA) 
where mA is the row and nA is the column
```

in getting  one maximum number but I cannot figure out how to choose another maximum number without duplication. I cannot sort because I need the indices.

Comment: Is this question about matlab or scilab? Please remove the unrelated tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this little trick.

```
 [output_val, output_index] = max(input_mat(input_mat < max(input_mat)))
```

This will give you the value and index of the second largest element. And then similarly, you can do it for 4 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the gsort function:

```
 [S,ind]=gsort(distA,"g","d");
```

The index of  the 4 largest elements is the given by

```
 ind(1:4)
```

Comment: if you want 4 distinct max values you can use the unique function. This function also sorts the data in increasing order

Comment: the max mavues are u($-3:$) and their indices are ind($-3:$)